# How add to weblogic 12c a JNDI custom resources as property

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, jndi, weblogic12c

How add to weblogic 12c a JNDI custom resources as property, 
I need to create a custom resource in weblogic to work as I have in Payara (Glassfish). It is a resource type properties.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 solutions:

1-properties file (apply to server)

2-web.xml (apply to application)

```
<env-entry>
<env-entry-name>iiopAppName</env-entry-name>
<env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
<env-entry-value>teste</env-entry-value>
```